# gcloud app ssl cert update failing with PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to update a SSL certificate for a Google App Engine project via CLI:

```
gcloud app ssl-certificates update NNNN --project XXX --configuration XXX --display-name=xxx.co.za --certificate=./fullchain.pem --private-key=./privkey_gae.pem
```

This command used to work previously but I am now getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.ssl-certificates.update) PERMISSION_DENIED: Caller is not authorized to administer this certificate. You must be a verified owner of the certificate's domain(s) [xxx.co.za, *.xxx.co.za] to create, modify, or delete this resource. Your authorized domain(s) are []. If you own the certificate domain(s), you can obtain authorization by verifying ownership via the Webmaster Central portal: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification.
```

This error does not make sense as the domains are verified according to the URL (as they are also the custom domain used by the app itself). Also this was working just last month, so it seems that something changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Domains are verified by an IAM user, but I use a different IAM/Service-account for the CI/CD server.

It seems that the security around accessing verified domains has changed, in that the Service-account will not automatically have access to the verified domains, even though the App does.

I was able to fix this issue by adding the service-account (jenkins@XXX-ci.iam.gserviceaccount.com) as verified owner here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification